# Can I add a GANTT chart from a subsite to a home page?

Tags: 2013, list, chart

I have several sub sites that have GANTT charts.  Is it possible to display each chart on the home page individually?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you have a few options. Which one to choose would depend on your exact requirements.

You can use the Page Viewer Web Part to accomplish this. It's not the prettiest solution, but it's easy and it works.

1. Create a GNATT view of the lists in the subsites.
2. Add a content editor web part with some CSS or JS/jQuery to hide all SharePoint UI components.
3. Add a Page Viewer Web Part to the desired page and link to the new GNATT view pages created.

You can use REST/JSOM to pull the GNATT data from the subsites. This is more complex, and would require you to render your own GNATT chart.

As a third potential solution, IF your requirements would allow, you could display the GNATT list data on the home page in a calendar view utilizing the Calendar roll up feature.

1. Create a Calendar view of each GNATT chart.
2. Create a Calendar on the home site for each GNATT chart.
3. Overlay the Calendar view of each GNATT chart onto the Corresponding Calendar.

Hope this helps!